# Terraform script destroying previously created ec2 before creating a new one

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I am new to Terraform and this is my first script trying it out

```
provider "aws" {
  profile    = "default"
  region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-2757f631"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

I have the script above stored on my windows desktop in `C:\TerraformScripts\First.tf`

Now when I run it the first time, the script executes and creates a new instance for me. I wanted to run it the second time with just changing the name from `example` to `example2`. I assumed it would create a new instance with the same configuration since I changed the name against the resource setting. But it instead destroyed the instance I had created on the first run and then recreated it again. Why is this happening without my specifying destroy?

Apologies, if I may have missed out something in the documentation, but I couldn't see it when I looked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform is a declarative language, which means that the script you write is telling terraform the state you want to get to (then terraform works out how to get there). It's effectively like saying "I want you to make sure I have an aws_instance", rather than "I want you to create an aws_instance".

If I'm understanding correctly, you are probably aiming to do this:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile    = "default"
  region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-2757f631"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example2" {
  ami           = "ami-2757f631"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

If you run `terraform apply` now, you will have two EC2 instances *regardless of how many were created by the script previously*. That's because under the hood, terraform is tracking the resources it's created previously for that script in a state file, comparing them to the current script, then working out what actions to take to make them line up.

Alternatively, you could use the `count` parameter to get multiple copies of the same resource:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile    = "default"
  region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  count         = 2
  ami           = "ami-2757f631"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I guess the history of what was created by the current .tf script is stored in the other state files it creates when running the apply script?

Comment: It stores the state that it has achieved after the apply command in the state file (so more of a point in time snapshot rather than a history), but yes pretty much. Their [state page](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/index.html) has a good summary at the top of what a state file does: "This state is used by Terraform to map real world resources to your configuration, keep track of metadata, and to improve performance for large infrastructures."